# The balance of Single responsibility/unit testability and practicality

Tags: unit-testing, oop, solid-principles

I'm still confused about unit testing. Suppose I have something as trivial as this:

```
class x {
    zzz someMethod(some input...) {
        BufferedImage image = getter.getImageFromFile(...);

        // determine resize mode:
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        Scalr.Mode resizeMode = (width > height) ? Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH : Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_HEIGHT;

        return ScalrWrapper.resize(image, resizeMode);
    }
}
```

Going by rules, *Scalr.Mode resizeMode =* should probably be a in a separate class for better unit testability of the aforementioned method, like so:

```
class xxx {
    mode getResizeMode(int width, int height)
    {
       return (width > height) ? Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH : Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_HEIGHT;
    }
}

class x {
   zzz someMethod(some input...) {
        BufferedImage image = getter.getImageFromFile(...);

        // determine resize mode:
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        Scalr.Mode resizeMode = xxx.getResizeMode(width, height);

        return ScalrWrapper.resize(image, resizeMode);
    }
}
```

But it looks like such an overkill... I'm not sure which one is better but I guess this way is better. Suppose I go this route, would it be even better to do it this way?

```
class xxx {
    mode getResizeMode(Image image)
    {
        return (image.getWidth() > image.getHeight()) ? Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH : Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_HEIGHT;
    }
}

class x {
   void someMethod(some input...) {
        BufferedImage image = getter.getImageFromFile(...);

        // determine resize mode:
        Scalr.Mode resizeMode = xxx.getResizeMode(image);

        return ScalrWrapper.resize(image, resizeMode);
    }
}
```

From what I understand, the correct way is the one where getResizeMode accepts integers as it is decoupled from the type of data whose properties are width and height. However, personally to me, the use of getResizeMode(BufferedImage) actually justifies the creation of a separate class better as some more work is removed from the main method. And since I am not going to be using getResizeMode for any sort of data other than BufferedImage in my application anyway, there is no problem of reusability. Also, I don't think I should be doing getResizeMode(int, int) simply for reusability if I see no need for it due to YAGNI principle.
So my question is: would getResizeMode(BufferedImage) be a good way according to OOD in **real world**? I understand it's text book good OOD, but then I have been lead to believe that 100% text book OOD is impracticle in real world. So as I am trying to learn OOD, I just want to know which path I should follow.
...Or maybe I should I just leave everything in one method like in the very first code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that resize mode calculation influences testability a lot.
As to Single Responsibility:
"A class should have only one reason to change" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Do you think that resizing mode calculation is going to change?
If not then just put in the class where this mode is needed.
This won't add any reasons to change for that class.

If the calculation is likely to change (and/or may have several versions)
then move it to a separate class (make it a strategy)

Comment: I agree with this line of thinking. Regarding testability it should be about functionality not implementation. The fact that the test is for "someMethod" rather than, say, "getMenuIcon" suggests your focusing on the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) is not about creating new classes every time, one extracting a method. Moreover the SRP depends on the context.

A module should concern to the SRP.
A class should concern to the SRP.
A method should concern to the SRP.

The message from Uncle Bob is: [Extract till you Drop](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop)
Beyond he said:

> Perhaps you think this is taking things too far. I used to think so too. But after programming for over 40+ years, I’m beginning to come to the conclusion that this level of extraction is not taking things too far at all.

When it comes to the decision to create new classes, keep the metric **high cohesion** in mind. Cohesion is the degree to which the elements of a module belong together. If all methods work in one specific context and on the same set of variables, they belong to one class.

Back to your case. I would extract all the methods and put them in on class. And this one class is also nicely testable.

Answer (score 0):

> Little bit late to the party, but here's my 2c.

To my mind, class x is not adhering to the SRP for a different reason.

It's currently responsible for

- Getting an image from a file (getter.getImageFromFile)
- Resizing that image

#### TL;DR

The TL;DR on this is that both of your approaches are fine and both do in fact stick - with varying degrees of stickiness - to the SRP. However if you want to adhere very tightly to the SRP (which tends to lead to very testable code), you could split this into three classes first:

#### Orchestrator

```
class imageResizeService
{
    ImageGetter _getter;
    ImageResizer _resizer;
    
    zzz ResizeImage(imageName)
    {
         image=_getter.GetImage(imageName);
         resizedImage=_resizer.ResizeImage(image);
         return resizedImage;
    }
}
```

- This class has a single responsibility; namely, given an image name,
  return a resized version of it based on some criteria.
- To do so, it orchestrates two dependencies. But it only has a single reason to change which is that the process used to get and resize an image in
  general , has changed.
- You can easily unit test this by mocking the `getter` and `resizer` and testing that they are called in order, that the `resizer` is called with the data given by the `getter`, and that the final return value equals that returned by the `resizer`, and so on (i.e. "[White Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing)" testing)

#### ImageGetter

```
class ImageGetter
{
    BufferedImage GetImage(imageName)
    {
       image=io.LoadFromDisk(imageName) or explode;
       return image;
    }
}
```

- Again, we have a single responsiblity (load an image from disk, and return it).
- The only reason to change this class would be if the mechanics of loading the image were to change - e.g. you are loading from a Database, not a Disk.
- An interesting note here is that this class is ripe for further generalisation - for example to be able to compose it using a `BufferedImageBuilder` and a `RawImageDataGetter` abstraction which could have multiple implementations for Disk, Database, Http, etc. But that's `YAGNI` right now and a conversation for another day :)

#### Note on testability

In terms of unit testing this, you *may* run into a small problem, namely that you can't quite "unit test" it - unless your framework as a mock for the file system. In that case, you can either further abstract the loading of the raw data (as per the previous paragraph) or accept it and just perform an integration test off a known good file. Both approaches are perfectly valid and you should not worry about which you choose - whatever is easier for you.

#### ImageResizer

```
class ImageResizer
{
    zzz ResizeImage(image)
    {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        Scalr.Mode resizeMode = getResizeMode(width, height);
        return ScalrWrapper.resize(image, resizeMode);
    }
    
    private mode getResizemode(width, height)
    {
        return (width > height) ? Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH : Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

- This class also has but a single job, to resize an image.
- The question of whether or not the `getResizeMode` method - currently just a private method to keep the code clean - should be a separate responsiblity has to be answered in the context of whether or not that operation is somehow independent of the image resizing.
- Even if it's not, then the SRP is still being followed, because it's part of the single responsibility "Resize an Image".
- Test-wise this is also really easy to test, and because it doesn't even cross any boundaries (you can create and supply the sole dependency - the image - during test runtime) you probably won't even need mocks.

*Personally* I would extract it to a separate class, just so that I could, in isolation, verify that given a width larger than a height, I was returned a `Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH` and vice-versa; it would also mean I could adhere to the [Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) whereby new scaling modes could be introduced without having to modify the `ImageResizer` class.

#### But really

The answer here has to be that that it depends; for example if you have a simple way to verify that, given a width of 100 and a height of 99, then the resized image is indeed scaled to "Fit to Width" then you really don't need to.

That being said I suspect you'll have an easier time testing this if you *do* extract that to a separate method.

> Just bear in mind that if you're using a decent IDE with good refactoring tools, that should really not take you more than a couple of keystrokes, so don't worry about the overhead.